# Is there a naming convention in PHP for methods getting next element from a collection?

Tags: php, collections

I've got a collection object and I'd like to get the collection items form it one by one: is there some standard or popular convention for naming a method that gets the next element from the collection? I named it `$collection->getItem()` but it's certainly wrong because it is in conflict with the widely accepted getter naming convention.

To clarify a bit, I provide a trivial example:

```
while($item = $collection->getItem()){
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: the naming convention should be underscore, but you are free to use camel case you know, just be consistent with it

Comment: There's the [`Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) which certainly is applicable to collections. If you're not utilizing that, you could at least follow it as contract; such as using `next()` as method name.

Comment: @meda I admit it is a matter of often personal preference, and even I myself would prefer the snake case, however the most widely accepted standard is nowadays PSR-FIG and it says methods MUST be named in camel case: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md And so in order not to divert the discussion from the topic I used the PSR-FIG naming standard.

Comment: @mario Well, `next()` only moves the pointer. It is the `current()` method that gets the item.